# moveit_servo pose tracking only works with Panda arm?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to follow along with the pose tracking example provided in moveit_servo on a UR10e and am having difficulty in understanding how to use this with an arm other than the panda arm.

Looking at the example, `moveit_servo::PoseTracking` takes a `moveit_servo::ServoParameters` object as a parameter([ref](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/humble/moveit_ros/moveit_servo/src/cpp_interface_demo/pose_tracking_demo.cpp#L128)). It seems this object can only be made with `moveit_servo::ServoParameters::makeServoParameters`([ref](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/humble/moveit_ros/moveit_servo/include/moveit_servo/servo_parameters.h#L121)) which makes all the parameters constant...

So how do I go about using this example with UR10e? Do I need to recompile `moveit_servo` to change `ServoParameters`? There are multiple parameters in this struct hardcoded to "panda" and I'd rather not compile from source.

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414977/moveit_servo-pose-tracking-only-works-with-panda-arm?/) by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2023-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe it should get and validate relevant parameters from the node ([see here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/humble/moveit_ros/moveit_servo/src/servo_parameters.cpp#L464)). Those `get()`and `validate()` methods are defined further up in the file: [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/humble/moveit_ros/moveit_servo/src/servo_parameters.cpp#L267) and [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/humble/moveit_ros/moveit_servo/src/servo_parameters.cpp#L354).

It seems like the parameter files passed to the node are hard-coded in the pose tracking example launch file [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/humble/moveit_ros/moveit_servo/launch/pose_tracking_example.launch.py#L18) but I think those YAML files are what you need to change.

---

Originally posted by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) with karma: 337 on 2023-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on 2023-05-04**:
I have customized those two yamls and use them just fine following along with the other examples (twist and joint cmd ones), but the pose tracking example seems to overwrite my yaml values with the values hard-coded in the struct...

**Comment by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) on 2023-05-04**:
I'll try it out and reproduce if I get a chance. I had a Servo+UR pose tracking setup working on Humble, but now that I think about it, I probably didn't use the `PoseTracking` class because I wanted to be able to use it with an existing, running Servo node.

I think maybe I just followed along to implement similar functionality.

**Comment by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) on 2023-05-06**:
I got the stock pose tracking demo executable working with the UR robots here: https://github.com/danzimmerman/servo_ur_pose_tracking_demo

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2023-05-07**:
Thanks Dan!

The pose tracking functionality is likely to change after Humble. A Google Summer of Code project is working on improvements so the PID gains of PoseTracking aren't required. Instead it will work like this:

provide target pose --> get IK solution --> move toward that solution as quickly as possible (bounded by vel/accel limits)

**Comment by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on 2023-05-08**:
Thanks Dan, I am still unable to get this working on actual hardware or the docker simulator but I don't have the errors regarding panda parameters anymore...

**Comment by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) on 2023-05-08**:
I was working on adding the UR robot driver launch to try getting the demo executable to work with URSim as an option in addition to fake hardware. However, the pose target update loop [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/humble/moveit_ros/moveit_servo/src/cpp_interface_demo/pose_tracking_demo.cpp#L172) doesn't run for very long, so I didn't think I could get External Control running on the "robot" before the demo node terminated.

I guess I could skip launching the ROS 2 Control nodes for real hardware/URSim, assuming that the driver, "robot" and ROS2 controller are all already up and running and ready to respond to joint position commands.

**Comment by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) on 2023-05-08**:
Andy M, I updated the repo so that if you pass `use_fake_hardware:=false` it should work with a robot driver that's already running and connected. Tested with URSim here: https://youtu.be/qYzdJA60K7w

I loaded `forward_position_controller` and had the External Control program already running in URSim so when I ran launched the example launch file from my repo, the robot was ready to accept commands from the pose tracker.